# Regular Expression: nested group

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace a string with part of its  substring,  i am using eclipse/notepadd to replace all such kind of instance in my project folder.

Example :

```
    sometext instanceof some == booleanvalue
    abc      instanceof xyz  == booleanvalue
    qwerty   instanceof keyboard == booleanvalue
```

Expected behaviour :

```
     !(sometext instanceof some)
     !(abc instanceof xyz )
     !(qwerty instanceof keyboard)
```

I am able to get the the whole string as `(.*)` o and partial as `(.*[^=])`
but I am not sure how can I replace my string with the partial.

Comment: Whay language/tool are you using? Do you want to remove `== booleanvalue`? Please, edit your question and add more test cases with expected result.

Comment: I am using Java and yes i want to remove the boolean value

Comment: my bad. .... will ask there

Comment: This is not really suitable for Stack Overflow in its current form. At the minimum, you should indicate what you have already tried.  Is splitting on `=` acceptable?

Comment: There is no "nested" group here, there is just a group.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ (is this what you're using?), try substituting

```
(\S+)\s+instanceof\s+([^=\s]+)\s*==\s*\S+$
```

with

```
!\(\1 instanceof \2\)
```

provided each statement is on a line of its own.

Comment: "I am using Java and yes i want to remove the boolean value " - please read the comments too

Comment: You can write perfectly good Java in Notepad++. Plus, he mentioned "Notepadd", so I figured. Moreover, regexes are exploitable with a number of tools and editors.